# HTML5 layout - What to do to get it work in Internet Explorer as well?

Tags: html, css

Following works like I want in all browsers but not in IE. In IE the content is shown below the menu and no header is displayed. Is there an easy was to get it work in IE as well?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="a_script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="a_css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="form.css">
<script src="jquery.tipTip.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="tipTip.css"> 
<title>andierni.ch</title>

</head>
<body>

<header class="shadow">

<hgroup>

    <h1>'</h1>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <a>Bitte besuchen Sie diese Seite mit einem modernen Browser.</a>
        <p>Meine Empfehlung ist Firefox: <a href="http://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/new/">Mozilla Firefox Download</a></p>
         <a>IE Nutzer: Ziehen Sie den Mauszeiger links weg vom Menü, um zum Inhalt zu gelangen.</a>
    <![endif]-->

</hgroup>    

</header>

<aside>

<p id="home">Home</p>
<p id="blogs">Blogs</p>
<p id="homepages">Homepages</p>
<p id="apps">Mobile Apps</p>
<p id="facebook">Facebook & Co.</p>
<p id="kontakt">Kontakt</p>    

</aside>

<div id="content" class="shadow">

    <img src="fuss2.png" alt="digital footprint" id="foot">

    <article id="welcome">

        <h1>andierni.ch</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2 id="textcolor">Welcome to my digital footprint!</h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>Diese Seiten geben einen Überblick</p>
        <p>über meine Web-Aktivitäten.</p>
    </article>


    <article id="browser">

        <a>Bitte besuchen Sie diese Seite mit einem modernen Browser.</a>
        <p>Meine Empfehlung ist Firefox: <a href="http://www.mozilla.org/de/firefox/new/">Mozilla Firefox Download</a></p>

    </article>



</div>

<footer>
<p class="copyright">
&copy; 2012 Andreas Erni
</p>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

And here the CSS:

```
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 130%;
width: 90%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #EEE;
}
header, aside, #content, footer {
background-color: #FFF;
}

/* display: block for new elements
not needed for browsers supporting them
*/
header, hgroup, article, aside, section, nav, footer {
display: block;
}


header {
margin: 10px 0px 3px 0px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
padding-left: 10px;

}
header img {
float: left;
padding: 5px;
width: 20%;
height: 20%;
}

header h1 {
margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;

}

aside {
border: 1px solid #CCC;
float: left;
width: 17%;
font-size: 0.9em;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#content {
border: 1px solid #CCC;
float: right;
width: 80%;
margin-bottom: 3px;
line-height: 0.3em; 
}

#content h2 {

font-size: large;
}

#content h3 {

font-size: small;
}

#content p, a {

font-size: smaller;
}

article {
padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
display: block;
}
article img {
float: left;
padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}
article p, a {
text-align: left !important;
line-height: 1em !important;
}

footer {
background-color: #EEE;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
font-size: 0.8em;
}

footer .copyright {
float: left;
margin-top: 3px;
padding-left: 3px;
font-size:0.9em;
color:#666;
}

.shadow {
-moz-box-shadow: 4px 0px 10px -3px silver;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 0px 10px -3px silver;
box-shadow: 4px 0px 10px -3px silver;
}

section {

display: block;
line-height: 1em;

}

section h1 {

padding: 20px;
margin-top: 10px !important;

}


.hover {

color: royalblue;

}

.tag {

float: right;
padding-left: 3px;

}

p, a {
line-height: 1.0em !important;
}

.abstand {

line-height: 1em;

}

.empty{

color: white;

}

#foot {

float: right;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;

}

#browser {

display: inline-block;
vertical-align: bottom;


}


#welcome{

float: left;
margin-top: 40px;

}

#welcomeB{

float: left !important;


}


#textcolor {

color: olivedrab;

}


header {

background: url("pA7.png");
background-color: white;

}

hgroup h1 {color: white;}
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks, Andi

Comment: id="content" should be displayed right of the <aside> block. In IE 8 the content is shown below the <aside> part and no header is displayed neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 and earlier do not support the HTML5 tags, and by default cannot display them properly.

The solution is a Javascript hack called [html5Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/). This hack fixes the display problems for HTML5 elements in old IE versions, as well as a couple of other minor bugs that occur with them.

You may also want to try out the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) script. This is a larger javascript tool which includes the htm5Shiv functionality, but also provides JS and CSS hooks to allow your code to know what HTML5 features are supported by the user's browser.

This javascript solution is the only known way to solve the HTML5 display issue in old IE versions. This means that you cannot support HTML5 tags for IE8 users who have Javascript disabled.

Answer (score 1):

For IE8 you need a html5shiv.

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Answer (score 0):

IE and firefox almost gives the same result on your code.

Try following this: Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

IE9 :
[image: IE9]

Firefox16 :
[image: FireFox16]

Comment: good to know that it works in IE9. I only have IE8 on XP. Have learnd a lot from the CSS tutorial. Thank you very much!